# Limit the number of web form entries, based on a field, to a set number

Tags: webforms, forms

I'm building a competition engine, the organisers are allowing users to submit 3 entries from the same email address. I can see that WebForms allows you to set fields to be unique, or set a number of form submissions allowed based on a cookie or IP. Sadly not on a per field basis.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've looked at the "webform_submission_user_limit_check" function which runs very logically, but I'm unsure about the best way of hooking into the function / replacing it.

Many thanks,

Dave.